# Custom listview onclicklistener on inner view

Tags: java, android, xml

i currently create an app that needs an custom listview. Everything with my listview is fine, but now i neet to know, how to set an onClickListener to an view, defined in my list_row.xml. i just want the onclicklistener on the whole item, and on this one inner view. I attach a picture to demonstrate my problem, because it is so hard to describe >.<
Picture (dropbox): https://www.dropbox.com/s/72xdxuwz47vl7s5/problem.png

I need a function that is called when clicking into the view [my Problem] indicates. its an ImageView filled with an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something I've done before that seems pretty similar to what you want to accomplish.

First, you declare an `onItemClickListener` for your `ListView`. This will handle standard list item taps (that is, taps inside a list item but outside the inner view region that you're concerned about). You can do this in a variety of places in your code, but `onCreate()` is a common one.

Example:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id ) {
    // Handle standard list item tap
    // ...
  }
} );
```

Then, you can just declare whatever `onClickListener`s you need for your inner view(s) inside your adapter's `getView()` method to handle click/tap events on your inner view.

Example:

```
@Override
public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
  LinearLayout itemView;

  // Inflate layout XML, etc.
  // ...

  // Find subviews in layout
  ImageView innerView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.myInnerViewId );

  // ...

  // Set up onClickListener for inner view
  innerView.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick( View v ) {
      // Handle inner view tap
      // ...
    }
  } );

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To set an OnClickListener in each row simply extend your current Adapter and override the `getView()` method.  In there you can define specific listeners as you normally would.

This is discussed in great detail in this [Google Talk](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html) by Romain Guy.